# Paginate Nestoria Results using PHP

Tags: php, pagination

I'm using the Nestoria API to retrieve property results.
Everything is working quite well and one can return up to 50 properties using this method.
I would like to show 10 items at a time and allow for the user to paginate through them, but for some reason I'm having difficulty doing this.

The code snippet around the section that controls this is as follows:

```
$page = isset($_REQUEST["page"]) ? (int)$_REQUEST["page"] : 1;
$page = $page-1;

$pagination = new pagination;
$propertyResults = $pagination->generate($nestoria->decodedData->response->listings, 10);

foreach($propertyResults as $listing) {
    //do stuff
}
```

A snippet of the data array would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [auction_date] => 
            [property_type] => house
            [summary] => Located in North Kingston a two double bedroom Victorian house presented in...
            [title] => York Road, Kingston, KT2 - Reception
            [updated_in_days] => 6.5
            [updated_in_days_formatted] => this week
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [auction_date] => 
            [property_type] => house
            [summary] => Fine home was built about 50 years ago and enjoys one of the best locations...
            [title] => Coombe Hill, KT2 - Conservatory
            [updated_in_days] => 2.5
            [updated_in_days_formatted] => this week
        )
    ....
```

(sample cut down due to size of array elements)

Now I have been staring at this for way too long now and I've drawn a blank.

This code works correctly except if I try go to any other page other than 1, then the page doesn't finish loading, it just carries on until Firefox says: "The page isn't redirecting properly".

So basically, pagination is able to cut my data array up correctly, but is failing to "paginate" correctly.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem with the redirect was actually an .htaccess issue which was using the $_GET["page"] variable and was therefore getting confused, so I renamed all references to the $_GET["page"] to $_GET["_page"] in this app.